# сохранения изображения из Qt WebEngine

Tags: qt

Не могу работать с QtWebKit, нужно именно с QtWebEngine (Qt 5.7).

Пытаюсь работать через `QNetworkAccessManager` с `downloadRequested(const QNetworkRequest &request)` и `downloadingIssueFinished()`.

Программа ругается при выполнении следующей строки:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager
    = ui->preview->page()->networkAccessManager();
```

Ссылается на то, что не работает с QtWebEngine, мол, функции такой там нет, а похожей не нашел. Как тогда вообще сделать сохранение картинки?

Comment: QtWebEngine не взаимодействует с `QNetworkAccessManager`. Но о какой картинке идёт речь? Расположенной на html-странице или, быть может, пытаетесь скачать её просто по прямой ссылке?

Comment: Во время работы с браузером (отобразил предположим страницу), если нажать правую мышку, предлагается сохранить изображение (Save File), хотелось сохранить его с его файлом а потом использовать дальше